# Intrasite links breaking with S3 redirect

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, filepath

I've got a static website setup with S3 and CloudFront. When I navigate to a subfolder like `example.com/nonexistant/`, my `example.com/index.html` page loads (as I want it to), however it's text only and all of my intrasite links get messed up.

For example, my logo is located at `example.com/img/logo.png`. When I navigate to `example.com/nonexistant/`, the html for `example.com/index.html` loads, however it now looks for my logo at `example.com/nonexistant/img/logo.png`.

So links like `<img src="img/logo.png">` are breaking because it is starting the search for the file from the wrong directory.

Is there a solution where I can fix something in my Redirection rules to have all pages ending in / redirect to example.com? I know I could probably just go edit my code to have all paths just appear as `<img src="https://www.example.com/img/logo.png">`, but I'm wondering if there is an easier fix here.

EDIT: I've already set up in CloudFront to have 404s go to /index.html with status code 200, and have in S3 set up my error document as index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your links to absolute paths, without the hostname.

```
 <img src="/img/logo.png">
```

S3 redirect rules can only match the key prefix -- the left-anchored part of the string, so they can't be used to address this.

You could also use a Lambda@Edge function in an origin response trigger, if you really wanted to *redirect* 404 responses for paths ending in `/` back to the main page, but a redirect rewrites the path in the address bar (by definition -- otherwise, it is not a "redirect"), and I assume since you are doing the 404-to-200 transformation then you are probably doing something like an SPA where you need the path to remain the same, despite index.html being displayed.

Comment: Changing the links from `path/to/file.png` to `/path/to/file.png` was the fix. This error really had nothing to do with S3 or Cloudfront. Thanks!